# Navigation with background above other div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a navigation on the top of my page and a div under the navigation. My html is like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Stop motion</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li><a href="facebook.com"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
        <li><a href="twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="stop_motion">
    <h2>Stop Motion Film: Het varken</h2>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="//www.youtube.com/embed/lGMWS7K_4Nk?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And my CSS now is like this:

```
nav{
    background: url(../images/navigation.jpg) no-repeat; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    height:210px;
    padding:10px;
    z-index:999;
}
    nav ul{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
        nav ul li{
            display:inline;
            font-family: 'ralewaysemibold';
            font-size:24px;
        }
            nav ul li img{
                width:36px;
                height:36px;
            }

#stop_motion
{
    background: url(../images/bg_stop_motion.jpg) no-repeat; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    z-index: -999;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    padding-top:150px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

But I want to have the second div under the first navigation. Not the whole 100% height but like 100px. I've tried adding margin-bottom: -110px; to the nav but then I get a result like this:

[image]

The second is div is just on top of the first, and it should be the other way around. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my CSS like this:

```
nav{
    background: url(../images/navigation.jpg) no-repeat; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    height:210px;
    padding:10px;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;right:0px;
}

#stop_motion
{
    background: url(../images/bg_stop_motion.jpg) no-repeat; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But now I get something like this:

[image]

I've also put it [online](http://beachteamvandenbroecke-engels.be/) so it makes it easier. (http://beachteamvandenbroecke-engels.be/)

The end result should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Please, send us the markup and css with this second div

Comment: what do you actually want to do?

Comment: Never use jpeg images for backgrounds that are not photos.Use PNG instead. You need to divide your background into two parts. The header and the half-circle. The header has to be relatively-positioned  and the circle must be absolutely positioned and (I guess) centered. Then you can position everything underneath without any problems. You can also try putting both the header and the circle absolutely with different z-indexes so that you can apply box-shadow and put a container with a top margin for everything underneath. Keep in mind that only PNG and GIF images have transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second div can have this markup:

```
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 210px; /*height of your nav*/
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -50px ; /* half of the div's width, must be a negative value. This is for centering purposes*/
 width: 100px;
 z-index: 100 /* more than the background's z-index*/
 }
```

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, I understand that you want the second div -under- the first. While your code shows:

```
#stop_motion {
    z-index: -999;
}
```

How about changing it to

```
#stop_motion {
    z-index: 998;
}
```

This would bring it above the first

Answer (score 0):

You could give the second div an absolute position, with a top of 100px and a z-index that's higher than the first.

Answer (score 0):

For `.nav` change the css

```
.nav{
    height:210px;
    padding:10px;
    z-index:100; /* higher z-index */
    position:absolute; /* to remove the nav from the flow of elements */
    left:0px;right:0px; /* to make the nav full width*/
}
```

Change the css for `#stop_motion` to this

```
#stop_motion {
    margin-top:230px; /* to bring the container below the nav, (is height of nav + top and bottom padding for nav) */
    z-index: -1; /* lower z-index*/
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6TruZ/5/)

---

In response to your update, I can see two problems,

```
nav{
    background: url(../images/navigation.jpg) no-repeat; 
    /*..more code..*/
}
```

1st. To remove that white background around the navigation, convert your background image to png or gif with transparency using an image editing software like Photoshop.

2nd. As nav is now `position:absolute;` it is out of the flow of the regular document structure, so the elements following it are going to begin from under it, to adjust for that you have to set its `margin-top` or `padding-top`.

```
#stop_motion {
    margin-top:230px; /* to bring the container below the nav, (is height of nav + top and bottom padding for nav) */
    /*..more code..*/
}
```

or

```
#stop_motion {
    padding-top:230px; /* to bring the container below the nav, (is height of nav + top and bottom padding for nav) */
    /*..more code..*/
}
```

As I see from the sample image of the result you have provided, using `padding-top` is more suitable.

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NfC67/embedded/result/)
Online Image Editor [pixlr.com](http://pixlr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use z-indexes, element has to be positioned (`position: relative/absolute/fixed`).

When element has default `position: static`, z-indexes are ignored.

Comment: Can you please link me an image, how it should look? I think you only want to make white color transparent on navigation.jpg, don´t you?

Comment: Thanks. If I understand you well, you need: 1. make white color on `navigation.jpg` transparent (and save as png), 2. `#stop_motion` has to have `position: relative; top: XXpx;`. Think it´s all, if not, please let me know with updated link.